# Can I retrieve cookies from guzzle response and set them to user's browser?

Tags: php, cookies, guzzle

Is it possible to realize such flow:

1. User puts login and password into form on my site and submits it
2. My server grabs data and uses Guzzle or another tool to make a request and proceed with authentication some site (for example facebook)
3. Facebook sends back cookies back to guzzle, which will contain some token(s) which will be used further.
4. Server sets cookies for the user. Next time user would like to go on facebook - he will be logged in (using grabbed earlier cookies)

I am using PHP and Guzzle on server, but it does not quite matter.
As I guess, it is not possible, because we should set cookies for another domain, which is not secure. But, I haven't found any alike topics, so I must be sure.

Thanks!

Comment: If you send any HTTP requests and get a response, you can read any headers from that response. See [Guzzle docs](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/http-client/response.html). Just read the `Set-Cookie` header and there you go. But you should not ask users for their Facebook or any other site's auth info!

Comment: @marekful First of all, i am not interesting in any of foreign's facebook accounts - I don't see there even a point to be interested in it. I don't know, where have you read it in my description. Secondary, my description tells, that I need to set these cookies, returned from facebook, into user's browser. Domain in facebook's returned header will be different from mine, so it will be cross domain cookie, and it won't work. I am just asking if there is a way, to play a role of "gateway" between user and foreign's service.

Comment: You say in (2) above that auth info submitted by user in (1) is forwarded to Fb. It is easy to interpret it that you ask for their Fb login.

Comment: The browser's behaviour when handling cookies is that a cookie sent by server in domain A cannot be set in domain B unless it is a subdomain of A. But you can get hold of the data in any cookie sent in response to your request. What you do with it its' up to you. You can set, for e.g. a cookie with the same name and value in your domain. Would like to explain further your overall goal?